# Pull from bottom View like Google Maps

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make an layout like the pull up menu (see pictures) in google maps, where I can pull up and see more details about a point on the map from the bottom of the screen.

I am currently pulling a side view using a DrawerLayout,

But I would use the same layout as google maps. Here is some images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e7is.jpg

Also, here is the code which I used in my main activity right now:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="neocom.dealerbook.MapFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/side_panel"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:name="neocom.dealerbook.SideBarFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/side_bar"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: half closed]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now we can use [Design Support Library: Bottom Sheets](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) from Android Support Library 23.2 !

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for contributing. I'll use it in my App when I get some time to change it. :)

Comment: I suggest everybody that wants this effect to use this solution. AndroidSlidingUpPanel was good when there isn't the Botton Sheet Support Library.

Answer (score 3):

This one did everything that I need [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)